# Free road distance calculator web service similar to Google Distance Matrix API

Tags: php, web-services, google-maps, google-api

As of now I am using Google's distance Matrix API for one of my project.

That is 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

It works fine, but the problem is, its not free after a certain quota.

So I just want to know, is there any other webservice which provides reliable distance calculator service for free?

Comment: Do you want to calculate distance between 2 place / point ?

Comment: distance between two Points, and it should be road map distance and not calculation based.

Comment: I know that this question have some years, but are you find some free api??

Answer (score 3):

Google API prices increased dramatically over the years. There are many cost effective alternatives available. Below are some of them:

-[TomTom](https://www.tomtom.com/en_us/drive/maps-services/maps/)

-[DistanceMatrixApi.com](https://www.distancematrixapi.com/)

-[Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/)

-[Here](https://www.here.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use scripts from here- http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Unfortunately these are spherical calculations and not road map distance.

Comment: s... I'm looking for road map distance.

Comment: Okay.. I think it couple be possible to calculate road/route length from the 'legs' of a route as returned by google direction service. Then again it is back to Google service and would involve lot of calculation and accuracy issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative that costs much cheaper than Google API does. Try [DistanceMatrix AI](https://distancematrix.ai/?utm_source=SFlow&utm_medium=Answer&utm_campaign=Dev_2). This API accounts for traffic conditions, calculates distances for driving, walking and bicycling modes.

Contact the creators and they’ll send you a trial version for free.

Disclaimer: I work at the company that creates this API.

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

You could use the [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) from google, together with the route, it also returns the distance.

Comment: It's free only up to a certain quota.

Comment: oh that's my problem @AndrewLeach.
Do you know any free services??